# Generating all possible combinations from a Data Frame in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to do something quite simple where I have 2 arrays that have been converted into a Data Frame, and I want to show all possible combinations. So for example my output at the moment looks something like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|         A |         B |
+-----------+-----------+
|     First |         T |
|    Second |         P |
+-----------|-----------+
```

However what I'm actually looking for is this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|         A |         B |
+-----------+-----------+
|     First |         T |
|     First |         P |
|    Second |         T |
|    Second |         P |
+-----------|-----------+
```

So far I've got some fairly straight forward code to map my arrays into columns but being quite new to using both Scala and Spark I'm not sure how I'd grab all those combinations. Here is what I have so far:

```
val firstColumnValues = Array("First", "Second")
val secondColumnValues = Array("T", "P")

val xs = Array(firstColumnValues, secondColumnValues).transpose
val mapped = sparkContext.parallelize(xs).map(ys => Row(ys(0), ys(1)))
val df = mapped.toDF("A", "B")

df.show

...

case class Row(first: String, second: String)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spark 2.3

```
val firstColumnValues = sc.parallelize(Array("First", "Second")).toDF("A")
val secondColumnValues = sc.parallelize(Array("T", "P")).toDF("B")
val fullouter = firstColumnValues.crossJoin(secondColumnValues).show
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great! Would this also work for more than 2 collections? Say I had 5 different collections that I wanted to combine into a single dataframe could I still do that with the same method here?

Comment: Hi, yes you can declare another collection and keep adding it in the join as below. But be very careful for large datasets. val thr= sc.parallelize(Array("1", "2")).toDF("C")
val fullouter = firstColumnValues.crossJoin(secondColumnValues).crossJoin(thr).show

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks. You said be careful for large datasets - is there a point where this becomes really inefficient?

Comment: Well... Inneficient is not really the problem, un-manageable is probably better suited. 4 columns of a thousand rows makes for a *trillion* rows crossjoin. A 64-CPU cluster will probably have lots of trouble doing anything non trivial a trillion times in a few hours.